# web3 define or set web3.eth.accounts[1]

Tags: web3js

For the call of a smart contract funtion i want to call it from a different account then the one i have currently in meta mask. So i want to call this method by:

`myContract.setFinished(true, {from: web3.eth.accounts[1], gas: 3000000}, function(err, res){});`

But currently `web3.eth.accounts[1]` is undefined, so how can i set this account with a given private key or/ and address?

Answer (score 1):

```
geth account new
```

and then Geth will ask you to set a password for the account. Simple as that!

Or in the console:

```
personal.newAccount("passphrase")
```

Answer (score 1):

In `web3` the accounts are handled as array, i.e. if your keystore contains wallets like

```
1. UTC--2017-11-29T07-19-07.738904169Z--d4cefe4bc33681c9eac5c0ecbca2f36c12a20561  
2. UTC--2017-11-29T09-29-42.039767053Z--ee0997d7deb637a4441c54c4547b61d059b269b6
```

Your `web3.eth.accounts[1]` would be `ee0997d7deb637a4441c54c4547b61d059b269b6`.

`web3.eth.accounts[1]` is undefined because you dont have a second address. You can create a new account as mentioned in the [above answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27660/259)